# Excel: Pivot Table with "% of Parent Row Total"

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I would like to build a pivot table in Excel in which the columns group by date (month) and there is only one column which calculates the percentages of parent totals. Is there a way to do that without Excel placing new columns in every month grouping.

My sample data is as follows:

[image]

If I build a pivot table with this data and group in the columns by month of date. I get the following:

[image]

But if I add another value which is calculated by "% of Parent Row Total" it does so for every month.

[image]

Is there a way to only have the last Column ("Gesamt: Summe von Price2") which calculates the percentages of the total sum, without having the new columns ("Summe von Price2") for every month. I know I can hide columns, but I am looking for a way to not create them at all.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not a way to do this natively with a pivot table. When I need something like this I will just make the extra column outside of the pivot table using a formula like the following which runs down the whole of column E assuming that **Gesamtergebnis** is in column D:

E2`=IF(ISBLANK($D2),"",$D2/MAX($D:$D))`

E3`=IF(ISBLANK($D3),"",$D3/MAX($D:$D))`

E4`=IF(ISBLANK($D4),"",$D4/MAX($D:$D))`

This obviously relies on the column total being the largest value in column D, so it won't work in some cases. For example if there were negative values in the Price column which made the largest value in Column D one of the *item rows* rather than the total row. But in that case you can just select the total row like: `=IF(ISBLANK($D2),"",$D2/$D$10)`